# Converting a developer certificate into a P12 file

Tags: ios, certificate

i am trying to Converting a developer certificate into a P12 file as a describbed [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html) using Virtual Machine  mac....but when converting

Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format  is disabled
what should i do

Comment: It is because you didn't selected the private keys associated with it.

Comment: The answer of Midhun is most likely correct. A p12 file is a file that contains both the certificate and the key. If you don't see the little expand icon next to your certificate in the keychain, you don't have a key.

Comment: @MidhunMP and Wolfgang are there any link that show how associated keys with certifacetes?thanks

Answer (score 41):

The .p12 option is disabled because, you only selected either the private key or the certificate on your machine. You need both of them for creating a .p12 file.

Steps to create .p12 file:

1. Run the  Keychain Access Application on your Mac.
2. Select the login keychain from the top-left panel
3. Select “My Certificates” from the “Category” menu in the left panel
4. Find your iPhone Developer/Distribution Certificate. DO NOT select iPhone Developer/Distribution: My Company
5. Expand this item, and inside you should see the Private Key.
6. Select BOTH the key and the certificate (Hold CMD and click both items)
7. Right click and select Export 2 Items...
8. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format, and call the file “Certificates.p12”
9. You will be prompted to create a password that is used when you attempt to import this key on another computer
10. Enter a password and save

Comment: in step 3-Select “My Certificates” from the “Category” menu in the left panel..........there is no certificate... it is empty ....when choose my certificates  category it is empty (http://yazilimsozluk.com/a.png)  but when choose all items category it show certificates (http://yazilimsozluk.com/a1.png)

Comment: @user1688401: From your comment, I think you did have the certificate and valid key in your machine. when you select the certificate is there any arrow present near to it ? Check this blog: https://appfurnace.zendesk.com/entries/22379207-How-do-I-create-p12-and-mobileprovision-files-for-iPhone-publishing-

Comment: where is that menu???this is my Keychain Access :http://yazilimsozluk.com/a2.png ....    ...Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority...

Comment: "Select BOTH the key and the certificate (Hold CMD and click both items)", i think to select certificate file is ok enough

Comment: In my case also, just exporting the certificate (parent of private key) worked. Exporting both certificate and private key did not work.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the certificate onto your machine?

Did you:

a) download it from the iOS cert portal
b) Send a certificate request from this very same computer and go thru the process to get it downloaded from the iOS cert portal

Note that option B means you have a private key associated with it because it was requested from this very same computer. If you are doing option A, then the private key is not on that machine

If you are trying to transfer your cert and private key from one computer to the next, the easiest way to do it is using the Keychain Access program, exporting the cert/key to *.p12 format for transfer.

If you open the Keychain Access program and find your developer certificate, click the arrow ned to it and make sure there is an associate sub key with it.

If so, right click the cert and click Export.

If not, then you need to do so from the original computer that the certificate was requested from to include the private key.

Comment: in virtual machine mac i downloaded (distribution )certificates from that url (https://developer.apple.com) and then  try to convert .p12 file as describbed in that link : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS144092a96ffef7cc-371badff126abc17b1f-7fff.html     but       Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format is disabled

Comment: Have you tried doing so from Keychain access instead? And what do you mean 'downloaded'? Do you mean you just downloaded them or you used a Cert Signing Request to create it? If it's the latter, as stated above, you instead need to export the cert/key from the original CSR machine.

Comment: just downloaded from https://developer.apple.com     what do you mean "Have you tried doing so from Keychain access instead?"  thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the Keychain Access Application I have moved my installed certification from the system folder to login folder (in left-top), then p12 exporting was enabled.

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me. I'd followed all the instructions to the letter, but double-clicking the `.cer` file was giving me an error in Keychain Access. So i created a custom keychain and dragged my cert file into that, but the p12 export option was disabled. Then I tried dragging the file into the "login" keychain and now I can export p12. Why the difference in behaviour? Nobody knows!